# Copy file from one folder to another and then rename using current date/time and new file ext using PowerShell or Python script

Tags: python, windows, shell, powershell, scripting

I do not have any experience with PowerShell scripts so I need some help to create a simple shell script.  The shell script needs to do the following:

1. The script will look for a file name with `.upl` file extension in the directory `M:\ProgramData\Aspect Software\Unified IP\Advanced List Management\tenant1\xfer\CRM_Upload.upl`.
2. The shell script needs to copy the `.upl` file and place it into a folder in the same directory, the destination folder is called "Uploads" (`xfer\uploads`).
3. The shell script also needs to append the current date/time (`hhmmssmmddyyyy`) onto the end of the file name after it has been copied to the Uploads folder with underscore  (`CRM_Upload_hhmmssmmddyyyy`).
4. Finally the shell script needs to change the file extension to `.txt` instead of the original `.upl` (`CRM_Upload_hhmmssmmddyyyy.txt`).

This as far as I got:

---

This is another stab I took at this using PowerShell script...I would prefer if it copied the file and renamed it instead of moving it.  Can someone help me with this below?

```
Function RenameMoveFile($locationPath, $fileName, $extension1, $extension2, $archiveFolder)
{
$date = Get-Date -uFormat ""%y%m%d-%H%M%S""
$old = $locationPath + $fileName + $extension1
$new = $locationPath + $fileName + "_" + $date + $extension2
$archiveFolder = $locationPath + $archiveFolder + "\"
Rename-Item $old $new
Move-Item $new $archiveFolder
}
## This is the only part that we'd edit
RenameMoveFile -locationPath "M:\ProgramData\Aspect Software\Unified      IP\Advanced List Management\tenant1\xfer" -fileName "CRM_DIALER_UPLOAD" -    extension1 ".upl" -extension2 ".txt" -archiveFolder "Uploads"
```

*** Here is a Python script I was trying to work on but its still not right..

import shutil
import datetime

#### Variable Definitions

```
from System import Environment
data_dir_base = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable('LMSRVSHARED')
xfer_dir = data_dir_base + "tenant1\\xfer\\"
source_file = xfer_dir + "CRM_DIALER_UPLOAD.txt"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
new_folder = xfer_dir + "Uploads\\"
dest = new_folder + '_' + str(date) + '.txt'
```

#### Main Script

shutil.copy(source_file, dest)

***With a little bit of hard work and trial and error I got the script working..

```
import shutil
import datetime

###   Variable Definitions
from System import Environment
data_dir_base = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable('LMSRVSHARED')
xfer_dir = data_dir_base + "tenant1\\xfer\\"
source_file = xfer_dir + "CRM_DIALER_UPLOAD.txt"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
new_folder = xfer_dir + "Uploads\\"
dest = new_folder + 'CRM_DIALER_UPLOAD' + '_' + str(date) + '.txt'

###   Main Script
shutil.copy(source_file, dest)
```

Comment: I didnt mention this really above but I was trying to make the script flexible so that if I wanted to use it in the future for another file extension I could by just changing the source file extension to something else other than .upl. Ideally I would like the script to look in the directory for the .upl then when it copies it to the new directory folder change it to .txt without hard coding file names.

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere :) ...I take it you're trying to use CygWin and sh/bash?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, I need the script to be written in Python or the much simpler version of PowerShell.  Can anyone help me out with the PowerShell version of this script?

Comment: I have this so far to just copy a file but I need it to do more than this as described above in my orignal post....

Copy-Item M:\ProgramData\Aspect Software\Unified IP\Advanced List Management\tenant1\xfer\*.upl M:\ProgramData\Aspect Software\Unified IP\Advanced List Management\tenant1\xfer\Uploads

Comment: @Kev ....I found out that the script needs to be written in PowerShell or Python either one.  Is there anyone on the community that can assist?  I took another try at the script but its not all the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import shutil
import datetime

###   Variable Definitions
from System import Environment
data_dir_base = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable('LMSRVSHARED')
xfer_dir = data_dir_base + "tenant1\\xfer\\"
source_file = xfer_dir + "CRM_DIALER_UPLOAD.txt"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
new_folder = xfer_dir + "Uploads\\"
dest = new_folder + 'CRM_DIALER_UPLOAD' + '_' + str(date) + '.txt'

###   Main Script
shutil.copy(source_file, dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

For shell scripting in windows you can use batch (.bat), but i prefer (.vbs)

Here is what you want with VbScript :

```
Dim fso, folder, objFolder, file, objFile
Dim strDir, strFileExtension, strNewDir, strNewExtension, strDate

' Parameters
strDir = "M:\ProgramData\Aspect Software\Unified IP\Advanced List Management\tenant1\xfer\"
strFileExtension = ".upl"
strNewDir = "M:\ProgramData\Aspect Software\Unified IP\Advanced List Management\tenant1\xfer\uploads\"
strNewExtension = ".txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(strDir) 

' create new dir
If Not fso.FolderExists(strNewDir) Then
Set objFolder = fso.CreateFolder(strNewDir)
End If 

' search for file, get date, then copy and rename
For each file In folder.Files    
    If (InStr(file.name, ".") > 0) Then
            If (LCase(Mid(file.name, InStrRev(file.name, "."))) = strFileExtension) Then

            ' get only the file name
            Set objFile = fso.GetFile(file.name)

            ' get date
            strDate = Right("0" & DatePart("h",now), 2) _
            & Right("0" & DatePart("n",now), 2) _
            & Right("0" & DatePart("s",now), 2) _
                & Right("0" & DatePart("m",now), 2) _
                & Right("0" & DatePart("d",now), 2) _
            & DatePart("yyyy",now) _

            ' copy file
            CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CopyFile file.name, strNewDir & fso.GetBaseName(objFile) & "_" & strDate & 

strNewExtension

         End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The script can be in python too if anyone knows how to write this in python

Comment: Sorry, my appologies, I just found out that the script needs to be either in Python (.py) or PowerShell (.ps1) scripting in order to work properly on the system that I have.  I will upadte my question subject header...

Comment: ok! i can't help you with .py and .ps1, but i think they are not very difficult to code